# Copy a table from a website using selenium and flask

Tags: python, selenium, flask, jinja2

For my local sports club website it would be nice to copy and sync the rankings and results from the official league website. I'm using flask and selenium for python 3.5.

So far I'm using

`driver.find_element_by_class_name("table")`

to locate the tables. Is there an efficient way to store this and pass this on to the jinja templates all at once? Or do I have to store and process all the different parts of the table (header, rows, elements) separately?

Comment: consider using BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 0):

As you have the information in a `<table>`, you should just extract the information based on `<tr>`, `<td>` (and possible `<th>`) and store that in a CSV or other structured file (YAML, JSON) and take the data for the jinja templates from there.

If you only update your file when data changes this is one of the more efficient ways, you can check e.g. every hour if the input (the official league table) changes.

This decoupling is also important for when the league data changes to use e.g. `<div>` and `<span>` and your input processing needs to be adapted.

@Will suggestion to use BeautifulSoup is a good one, especially if the data is to process is large, a one time retrieve of HTML from selenium and processing by BeautifulSoup is much faster. If you are not willing to investigate time into that look at using full CSS (not just class) for selecting elements in `selenium` (using `.find_element_by_css_selector()` ) that is most easily translated to BeautifulSoup (using `.select()`), once you are going to make the transition.